# Modify word separator in hunspell

Tags: hunspell

If I have these 2 words, the first one is underlined and the second is considered correct.

```
juunk-test and-this-is-test
```

This is expected behaviour. The option '**junk-test**' is shown for the first word. great.

Is there any way that only the first word "juunk" is underlined and "junk" is shown as a suggestion?